# bootsrap3 : how to add inline select and input so it fits all width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a quick snippet using bootstrap:

select + input + 3 buttons so it all fits 1 single row (inline)

https://jsfiddle.net/tso3oseg/

```
<div class="well well-sm margin-bottom-no">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">all</option>
        </select>
          <input type="text" id="chatInput" class="form-control " placeholder="Ecrire texte ici...">      
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn  btn-pretty" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-pretty" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-pretty" id="sendBtn" type="button">Send</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I cannot make the input and select fit the same line.

Result is: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your answer check the code at [codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/kXdgEV?editors=1000)

```
<div class="well well-sm margin-bottom-no">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">all</option>
        </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
    <input type="text" id="chatInput" class="form-control " placeholder="Ecrire texte ici...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn  btn-warning" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-pretty" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-pretty" id="sendBtn" type="button">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: GREAT ! but could you explain... especially that span inout-group-addon with width:0px ?

Comment: I know that solution because i have faced that once in my project. In input-group component you cannot have two input field simultaneously next to each other you have to have either input-group-addon or input-group-btn between them, Otherwise there will be whitespace always between them. so by placing them between the two inputs and setting width to 0, solves our problem. Hope it makes some sense.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `form-inline` and wrap the input in `input-group-btn`..

```
<div class="well well-sm margin-bottom-no form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="1">all</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="text" id="chatInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Ecrire texte ici..."> 
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn  btn-pretty" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-pretty" id="attachBtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-pretty" id="sendBtn" type="button">Send</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/DuYpzrhZIR

Comment: works.. but it does not fill the whole div.well any more !